# MediaElement in Windows10

Tags: wpf, windows-10

I used `WPF` `MediaElement` in my project, when I run it on `Windows 10`, the music doesn't begin. I searched about it and found that I should install `Windows 10 Media Feature Pack`.
If I publish my app, I cannot guarantee that everyone has it, please suggest me what to do? should I use any other control instead of it?

Comment: At least tell us if you are trying to play audio or video.

Comment: I try to play audio

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

In order to understand the issue we have to set MediaFailed event and see what is wrong with you media element. I don't think that Windows 10 Media Feature Pack is the problem but I am not sure. Here is how my media element looks like and plays very well:

```
   <MediaElement
        x:Name="audioPlayer"
        LoadedBehavior="Manual"
        MediaFailed="audioPlayer_MediaFailed"
        Source="music.mp3"
        Volume="1" />
```

And here is how you can debug what's wrong with it:

```
private void audioPlayer_MediaFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.ErrorException.Message);
}
```

Your media elements should also be copied. Click on your .mp3 file's properties and make sure that Build Action is Copy if newer or Copy always.

Comment: I am sure it is because of Windows 10 Media Feature Pack, when I run your code the error is "windows Media Player version 10 or later is required".